# All math in chapter or section titles is messed up after updating to latest TL 2022

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I found a problem in math generated after updated to latest TL. All math in chapter and/or section titles is messed up now. This used to show up OK before I updated to TL. I've used this for years before with no problem.

The math which is not in section or chapter title still shows OK.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{my book title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter}   
\TocAt{chapter,section}
\TocAt{section,subsection}
\TocAt{subsection,subsubsection}
\TocAt{subsubsection,paragraph}
\fi 

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{First order ode $F\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)  =0$}%

The equation is  $F\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)  =0$

\section{First order linear in derivative $F\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)=0$}%
These are first order ode's which are linear in $y^{\prime}$.
\subsection{Quadrature ode $y^{\prime}=f\left(  x\right)  $}
data
\subsubsection{Introduction}
data
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  index.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

This is the HTML

[image]

Notice all those `\o` stuff. Before updated TL this all worked OK and the math showed up OK in section and chapter titles. So something changed.

This is the raw HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title>my book title</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='index.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='indent'>
</p>   
<div class='maketitle'>
<h2 class='titleHead'>my book title</h2>
<div class='author'><span class='ec-lmr-12x-x-120'>me</span></div><br />
<div class='date'><span class='ec-lmr-12x-x-120'>December 26, 2022</span></div>
</div>
<h2 class='likechapterHead' id='contents'><a id='x1-1000'></a>Contents</h2>
<div class='tableofcontents'>   
<span class='chapterToc'>1 <a href='#first-order-ode-fleft-xyy-right-' id='QQ2-1-2'>First order ode \(F\o:left: ( x,y,y^{\prime }\o:right: ) =0\)</a></span>
</div>
<!-- l. 27 --><p class='indent'>
</p>   
<h2 class='chapterHead' id='first-order-ode-fleft-xyy-right-'><span class='titlemark'>Chapter 1</span><br /><a id='x1-20001'></a>First order ode \(F\left ( x,y,y^{\prime }\right ) =0\)</h2>
<div class='chapterTOCS'>   
 <span class='sectionToc'>1.1 <a href='#first-order-linear-in-derivative-fleft-xyy-right-' id='QQ2-1-3'>First order linear in derivative \(F\o:left: ( x,y,y^{\prime }\o:right: )=0\)</a></span>
</div>
<!-- l. 29 --><p class='indent'>   The equation is \(F\left ( x,y,y^{\prime }\right ) =0\)
</p>   
<h3 class='sectionHead' id='first-order-linear-in-derivative-fleft-xyy-right-'><span class='titlemark'>1.1   </span> <a id='x1-30001.1'></a>First order linear in derivative \(F\left ( x,y,y^{\prime }\right )=0\)</h3>
<div class='sectionTOCS'>   
  <span class='subsectionToc'>1.1.1 <a href='#quadrature-ode-y-fleft-xright-' id='QQ2-1-4'>Quadrature ode \(y^{\prime }=f\o:left: ( x\o:right: ) \)</a></span>
</div>
<!-- l. 32 --><p class='indent'>   These are first order ode’s which are linear in \(y^{\prime }\).
</p>   
<h4 class='subsectionHead' id='quadrature-ode-y-fleft-xright-'><span class='titlemark'>1.1.1   </span> <a id='x1-40001.1.1'></a>Quadrature ode \(y^{\prime }=f\left ( x\right ) \)</h4>
<div class='subsectionTOCS'>   
   <span class='subsubsectionToc'><a href='#introduction' id='QQ2-1-5'>Introduction</a></span>
</div>
<!-- l. 34 --><p class='indent'>   data
</p>   
<h5 class='subsubsectionHead' id='introduction'><a id='x1-5000'></a>Introduction</h5>
<div class='subsubsectionTOCS'>   
</div>
<!-- l. 36 --><p class='indent'>   data
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Using

```
>which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
>make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3l
```

Ticket at https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?589

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you encounter issues with math commands in TOC with the MathJax mode, you usually need to declare the problematic command using the `\fixmathjaxtoc` command. In this case, the issue is with `\left` and `\right`, so you can declare them using:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\fixmathjaxtoc\left
\fixmathjaxtoc\right
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. That fixed it. But I am really confused. Why was it working OK before I updated TL last night?  I have been doing this for long time without these commands you showed and this is the first time I saw these funny characters show up in table of content. Any way, thanks for the fix.

Comment: @Nasser I am not sure. When was the last time you updated your distro? I've changed `\left` and `\right` to be robust commands in August, but I don't think this change should cause this issue.

Comment: Last time I've updated TL (other than last night) was long time ago. May be before august. I do not update TL much as I am afraid something will break when I do :)

Comment: @Nasser at least I got lot of bug reports when you do the update. Anyway, it is possible that it was some other change, it could be change in LaTeX core as well.

Comment: No problem. Complicated software so anything can happen. Thanks again for the fix.