handling \raisebox in tex4ht with mathjax mode
Latex generated by Maple uses \raisebox in some places. This causes problem in mathjax.
First will show the MWE and then show some attempts I made to fix it but it is not working well.
I can't modify the code generated since this is auto-generated each time the program is run. I can however add anything I want in the preamble or before the code.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hyperref}%needed by Maple
\usepackage{breqn}%needed by Maple
\usepackage{maple}

\begin{document}

\[%everything from here to closing \] was generated by Maple 2024
\begin{array}{lll}
 & {} & \textrm{Let's solve} 
\\
 {} & {} & \left[x^{\prime \prime}+9 x=10 \cos \left(2 t \right), x \left(0\right)=0, 
           x^{\prime}{\raisebox{-0.36em}{$\Big |$}}{\mstack{}{_{\left\{t \hiderel{=}0\right\}}}}=0\right] 
\\
 \bullet & {} & \textrm{Highest derivative means the order of the ODE is}2 
\end{array}
\]
    
\end{document}

The above compiles OK as is using lualatex

Note that you need maple style file to compile the above. At the bottom I have zip file which includes everything in it needed.
Compiling the above using tex4ht gives
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug A.tex "mathjax,htm,nostyle"


The \hiderel comes from breqn which Maple needs (i.e. Maple Latex generated assumes this package is there. But mathjax does not know about these.
Next, I modified my .cfg and nulled these commands in mathjax mode. Here is my .cfg file (it is also in the zip file below)
\Preamble{xhtml,p-width}
%this disables make4ht loading mathjax
\Configure{MathjaxSource}{}

%now loads mathjax  

\Configure{MathjaxSource}{https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js}

%V3.0
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{  
  tex: {
    tags: "ams",
    maxBuffer: 40*1024,
    packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']},
    \unexpanded{%
    macros: {      
        sp: "^",
        sb: "_",      
      moverset: ["\\mathop{\#2}\\limits^{\#1}",2],
      munderset: ["\\mathop{\#2}\\limits_{\#1}",2],
      moversetsp: ["\\mathop{\#2}\\limits^{\#1}",2],
      mundersetsp: ["\\mathop{\#2}\\limits_{\#1}",2],
      eslowast: ["{}"],
      mcoloneq: ["{}"],
      mstack: ["{}"],
      hiderel: ["{}"],
      raisebox: ["{}"]
    }},
    autoload: {
      color: [],
      colorV2: ['color']
    },
    packages: {'[+]': ['noerrors','textmacros']}
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',
    processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/noerrors','[tex]/textmacros']
  }
};
}

%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669770/problem-2-after-updating-to-latest-tl-2022-all-math-in-chapter-or-section-titl
\fixmathjaxtoc\left
\fixmathjaxtoc\right

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

And now compiled again using the above .cfg
  make4ht -ulm default -a debug -c ./nma_mathjax.cfg A.tex "mathjax,htm,nostyle"


Better, but still not working like in the PDF.
Is there a way to make it show like in the PDF using mathjax mode?
The following zip file contains all the files needed to compile the above (maple.sty and the .cfg and the latex file)
ls -lrt
total 208
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me autologin   1293 May  3 14:45 nma_mathjax.cfg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me autologin    588 May  3 14:52 A.tex
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me autologin  63776 May  3 14:53 A.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me autologin 135645 May  3 15:03 maple.sty

Save link. My own web page.
may_3_2024.zip
Using texlive 2023 on Linux

Unfortunately, MathJaX is off-topic for this site.

something like raisebox: ["\\style{margin-top:0.35em;display:inline-block;}{\#2}",2] should work in theory, but it doesn't, there is no lowering. But at least it will remove the dimension from your math output. There are still dollars though. I don't know how to remove these, except for some post-processing of the generated HTML.

While MathJax doesn't support \raisebox, it supports \raise. So you can redefine \raisebox in the following way in the config file:
raisebox: ["\\raise{\#1}{\#2}",2]

It produces a following result:

As you can see, there are spurious $ characters. I don't know how to configure MathJax to ignore them, but you can clean them from the HTML file itself using make4ht filters. Try the following build file:
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local process = filter {
  function(s)
    -- change \raisebox to \raise, which is supported by MathJax
    local s = s:gsub("\\raisebox%s*(%b{})(%b{})", function(a,b)
      -- remove $ characters inside \raisebox
      b = b:gsub("%$", "")
      return "\\raise" .. a .. b
    end)
    return s
  end
}

Make:match("html$", process)

It converts \raisebox to \raise and also removes $ characters. The result looks much better:

